# Files are slipping through my check

Tags: bash

I have a bash script which recursively prints the sizes of files

```
for x in `ls $1`; do
    if [[ -d $x ]]; then
        echo "Going into $x"
        bash `readlink -en $0` `readlink -en $x`
        echo "Returning to parent"
    elif [[ -f $x ]]; then
        wc -c $x
    elif [[ -h $x ]]; then
        echo "Symbolic"
    elif [[ -b $x ]]; then
        echo "block-special"
    elif [[ -c $x ]]; then
        echo "character-special"
    elif [[ -p $x ]]; then
        echo "pipe"
    elif [[ -S $x ]]; then
        echo "socket"
    else
        echo Skipping $x
    fi
done
```

But some files are falling through to the else statement. For example,

```
$ stat Desktop.tar.gz
  File: 'Desktop.tar.gz'
  Size: 1884        Blocks: 8        IO Block 4096    regular file
...
```

So even though Desktop.tar.gz is labeled as a regular file, it's not caught by `if [[ -f $x ]];`... Why might that be? It's not just a couple files either, it's *most* of them.

```
$ ls
backup                       csc         Desktop    etc         forkres
IdeaProjects  log       ppid    s3       Templates   Videos
```

bin
csc.7z      Documents  forkbomb    forktime  include       Music     ppid.c  scratch  timefork
Brackets.Release.1.6.64-bit  csc.tar.gz  Downloads  forkbomb.c  fileSizes.sh  lib           Pictures  Public  share    timefork.c

```
$ bash fileSizes.sh .
Going into backup
Skipping backup.tar.gz
Skipping bin.tar.gz
Skipping Brackets.Release.1.6.64-bit.tar.gz
Skipping csc.7z.tar.gz
10151 csc.tar.gz
Skipping csc.tar.gz.tar.gz
Skipping Desktop.tar.gz
...
Skipping Videos.tar.gz
Returning to parent
Going into bin
Skipping drracket
Skipping gracket
Skipping gracket-text
...
Skipping unsplit
Returning to parent
Going into Brackets.Release.1.6.64-bit
Skipping control.tar.gz
...
Returning to parent
Going into csc
Skipping rootkey(1).csv
Skipping rootkey.csv
154 forkbomb.c
307200 forkres
8776 forktime
533 hw4_2.sh
Going into IdeaProjects
Skipping cscsh
Returning to parent
...
8768 ppid
524 ppid.c
8776 timefork
395 timefork.c
Going into Videos
Returning to parent
```

Some prints not listed (...) for the sake of readability.

Comment: Do any of your file names have spaces in them? Perhaps you can show a few samples of names that are skipped versus a few names that work properly.

Comment: Some of them, probably (it's running on a lot of files), but even ones that don't are slipping through.

Comment: Certainly `for x in \`ls $1\`` is going to give you an issue with file names that have spaces. But again, it would help if you showed some additional examples to see what else may be happening. And what are you giving for the `$1` argument when you run your script? It would help to show how you run the script as well. If you put `echo "$x"` as the first line after the `for` statement line you might see some helpful output.

Comment: Just noticed: what's the colon (`:`) for at the end of `do`? It doesn't do anything and is unnecessary. It's not part of the syntax of the `for ... ; do`, although it's harmless in this particular context.

Comment: Added an example, although it's kind of wordy (again, lot of files).

Comment: Now that you're showing your actual code, it's clear. It skips the files that are in subdirectories because it is looking for them in the current directory (the directory where you are executing your script from). Your "going into" doesn't really "go into" the directory. It stays in the current directory, but looks for the subdirectory files there. And you're still going to have problems with file names that have spaces in them ultimately. ;)

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. I've fixed it by changing the first few lines to. `for x in $(ls $(readlink -en $1)); do
 x=$(readlink -en $1)/$x`

Comment: [Don't parse `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Comment: Is there an alternative? Globs can't take arguments or expand anywhere except the cwd.